# Pluggable .NET 4.5 Ribbon

Tags: c#, .net, ribbon

I am looking for a way to provide a pluggable way to add items to the .NET 4.5 ribbon, and have made a few strides in doing so, but not quite the way I'd like it:

```
[InheritedExport]
public interface IRibbonItem
{
    void Compose(DesignerRibbon ribbon);
}

public class TestItem : IRibbonItem
{
    public void Compose(CustomRibbon ribbon)
    {
        ribbon.ApplicationMenu.Items.Add((new RibbonApplicationMenuItem() { Header = "_Hello, World!" }));
    }
}

public class MEFRibbon : System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon.Ribbon
{
    [ImportMany]
    private IEnumerable<IRibbonItem> _oRibbons = null;

    public MEFRibbon() : base()
    {
         this.ApplicationMenu = new RibbonApplicationMenu();
         MEFHelper.Instance.ComposeParts(this);
         this._oRibbons.ToList().ForEach(x => x.Compose(this));
    }
}
```

While this works, it seems messy.  I'd prefer to write all of the plugins' content in XAML.  Is there a way I can achieve this goal?

Everything I've looked at references the old Ribbon or some other library.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issues so far. 
The goals I've planned to achieve:

- The application should be extensible via plugins.
- Application plugins should be able to add their own UI content into predefined UI regions: ribbon tabs, ribbon application menu, ribbon quick access toolbar and status bar.
- The application should be built within MVVM architecture as close, as it possible.
- Plugin developer should be able to describe UI content in XAML. There shouldn't be any view model types, which reproduce hierarchy of ribbon controls (such as `RibbonTabViewModel`, `RibbonButtonViewModel`, etc), because this leads to parallel hierarchy of classes, and limits the abilities of XAML.
- Plugins should use MEF to be loaded into host application.

Here's the approach I've used.
All my plugins are decorated with `[ApplicationExtension(...)]` and implement `IApplicationExtension`:

```
public interface IApplicationExtension
{
    void Startup();
    bool CanShutdown();
    void Shutdown();
}
```

`ApplicationExtension` is declared as:

```
[MetadataAttribute]
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false)]
public sealed class ApplicationExtensionAttribute : ExportAttribute, IApplicationExtensionMetadata
{
    public ApplicationExtensionAttribute(/* ... */)
        : base(typeof(IApplicationExtension))
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.UICompositionOrder = uiCompositionOrder;
    }

   // ...
}
```

`IApplicationExtensionMetadata` - some metadata, such as display name, etc.

Host application, in turn, implements this interface:

```
public interface IApplicationInfrastructureProvider : IInfrastructureProvider
{
    ICollection<ViewModel> RibbonTabs { get; }
    ICollection<ViewModel> ApplicationMenuItems { get; }
    ICollection<ViewModel> QuickAccessToolbarItems { get; }
    ICollection<ViewModel> StatusBarItems { get; }
}
```

where `ViewModel` - some base view model class, and loads plugins via MEF:

```
    [ImportMany]
    private IEnumerable<Lazy<IApplicationExtension, IApplicationExtensionMetadata>> Extensions { get; set; }
```

When application initializes, it calls `Startup` method for each plugin.
Here plugin implementation is able to add tabs, menu items, etc. via `IApplicationInfrastructureProvider` as view models to extend application's UI.

Note, that these view models **are not** any `RibbontTabViewModel` or `RibbonButtonViewModel`. They are just some pieces of functionality.

How it works at the UI side.
When, for example, `RibbonTabs` collection is changed, application calls custom service, which performs this job:

- First, it lookups a resource dictionary for the view model. For simplicity, I'm using naming conventions: if the type of tab view model is `MyCustomVm`, the service looks for `MyCustom.xaml` in the same assembly.
- Second, the service explores resource dictionary and looks for resource, whose key ends with `_RibbonTabKey`. View model becomes the data context of found resource. This assumes, that resource is at least `FrameworkElement`.
- Third, the found resource is being added to `RibbonTabsUI` collection of host application.

The ribbon is bound to the `RibbonTabsUI` in XAML for host application:

```
<r:Ribbon x:Name="ribbon" Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding RibbonTabsUI}">
    <!-- other content -->
</r:Ribbon>
```

The sample of ribbon tab looks like this:

```
<r:RibbonTab x:Key="MyCustom_RibbonTabKey" x:Shared="False">
    <r:RibbonGroup Header="Some group">
        <!-- other content -->
    </r:RibbonGroup>
    <!-- other content -->
</r:RibbonTab>
```

`ApplicationMenuItems` and `QuickAccessToolbarItems` are being processed the same way, the difference is the resource key suffix.

Comment: This is a very solid idea, thank you for your input!